# jQuery this.id selector syntax issue?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have what I feel is quite a simple problem

I have a series of 6 images with ids running 1-6, and I want to run a mouseover function. The following code works

```
<script>$('#0').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#1').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#2').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#3').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#4').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#5').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
<script>$('#6').mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
```

But I want to write this as a single line. I thought the following should work, but it does not. What am I missing please?

```
<script>$('#' + this.id).mouseover(function(){alert(this.id)});</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply all the id selectors to a single object as a comma separated string:

```
$('#0, #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6').mouseover(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Or, better still, put a common class on all those elements and select by that one class:

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Isn't it `$(this).attr("id")` in the jQuery way??

Comment: You can do that, but you can already get the `id` property form the DOMElement referenced by `this`, so creating a new jQuery object to get a property you already have access to is redundant.

Comment: May be redundant, but more consitent. But okay, you're not wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

The instance `this` in a jQuery event handler contains the current element matched by the selector you have provided. It is only available within the callback function. This is the correct approach:

```
$('#0, #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6').mouseover(function() {
    alert(this.prop('id'));
});
```

Also note that in order to get the id of an element, you should use `this.prop('id')` (for DOM element) or `this.attr('id')` (for HTML element)